# How do I run the sphere-slicer.pl perl command to make a photo into a sphere?

Tags: command-line, perl

I was looking for a program to slice pictures somehow to paste it on a globe(sphere). I found ip-slicer in this website. http://www.bruno.postle.net/2001/ip-slicer/ 
The problem I have is that I don't know where should I enter the command line. for example after running the program and entering this line "sphere-slicer.pl 16 1000 input.jpg" I get this this error

```
Number found where operator expected at - line 72, near "pl 16"
    (Do you need to predeclare pl?)
Number found where operator expected at - line 72, near "16 1000"
    (Missing operator before  1000?)
Bareword found where operator expected at - line 72, near "1000 input"
    (Missing operator before input?)
```

This program is written in perl language.

Comment: We do have an existing question that addresses what software can make a sphere. It sounds like your particular question is very direct about how to use this particular software though. See: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17321/is-it-possible-to-print-a-photo-so-it-can-be-mounted-on-a-globe

Comment: I exactly did what this link said to do and I got this error.

Comment: You are running this via imagemagick, yes?

Answer (score 2):

The error message you give indicates that you ran the `perl` command and then typed "`sphere-slicer.pl 16 1000 input.jpg`".

That's a reasonable guess, but that's not how Perl works. Perl is an *interpretted* language, and can read its program either from a script (a `.pl` file) or from "standard input" (which is what you get when you type to it after just running perl).

So, when you type "`sphere-slicer.pl 16 1000 input.jpg`", it's telling you, essentially: "Huh? You're not speaking my language." (The errors tell you *specifically* what it didn't understand, which would be useful if you *were* entering Perl but making a mistake. Here, you're not entering Perl at all — you're entering the shell command line, which literally *is* a different language.)

Fortunately, this is simply corrected. If your command line is Linux, Mac, or Cygwin under Windows, you can make the script executable and then refer to its path in the current directory, like this:

```
chmod +x sphere-slicer.pl
./sphere-slicer.pl 16 1000 input.jpg
```

Or, you can just prefix the command with `perl`, and the perl program will read the script from its first parameter and pass the rest along. So:

```
perl sphere-slicer.pl 16 1000 input.jpg
```